# Why is zip(*) not restoring my original list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to understand what is happening:

```
a = list('hello world')
b = [a[i::l]for i in range(8)]
```

I would then expect that:

```
zip(*b) == a
```

However what I get is the following:

```
 [('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o')]
```

Maybe it's a failing on my part to understand what zip(*) doe but I thought it unpacks a list of list and makes a single list out of it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because `zip()` stops *when shortest iterator* has run out.

Comment: What is `l` in the `b` list comprehension?

Comment: Since `zip` always returns an iterable of tuples, `zip(*b)` can't possibly be equal to `a` (which is a list of strings, not tuples).

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is freely available. There's no need to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a detail specific to `zip()`, as [outlined in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted

`hello world` has 11 characters in it, a prime number, so apart from a list of 11 separate sequences with each one character, there is no way to produce a list of lists without at least one of those being shorter.

For example, if we presume that `l = 8` (anything 5 and over would produce the output you've shown), then `a` is set to:

```
[['h', 'r'], ['e', 'l'], ['l', 'd'], ['l'], ['o'], [' '], ['w'], ['o']]
```

That's 8 lists, with the first containing 2 elements, the remainder have just one. So only the *first elements* of these are then used to produce combinations:

```
>>> [l[0] for l in b]
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o']
```

You only looped 8 times, so there only 8 top-level lists in `b` to take letters from. For different values of `l` of 5 or up you'll get a different distribution of the remaining letters but with only 3 more characters remaining there aren't many ways of distributing those remaining letters across the lists, and with `l` below `8`, you just add repeated letters (as `[0::l]` and `[7::l]` are guaranteed to overlap for any `l` equal to 7 or lower).

You'd have to loop up to 11 times and take every 11th character to get something that'll zip to the same sequence:

```
>>> b = [a[i::11]for i in range(11)]
>>> b
[['h'], ['e'], ['l'], ['l'], ['o'], [' '], ['w'], ['o'], ['r'], ['l'], ['d']]
>>> list(zip(*b))
[('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')]
```

*This still isn't the same as `a`*, because `zip()` produces sequence of sequences (here it's just one because there is only a single value in each nested list). You could use `next()` to get the first (and only) element:

```
>>> a == list(next(zip(*b)))
True
```

You can instead use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to continue iteration until the *longest* input iterable is exhausted, and add a default filler value to augment the shorter sequences. An empty string would work if you wanted to join the sequences back to whole strings again:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 2 has the same object, but with i prefixed
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

result = list(zip_longest(*b, fillvalue=''))
```

This however produces **two** tuples; there are two columns in the input, after all:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> b = [a[i::8]for i in range(8)]
>>> list(zip_longest(*b, fillvalue=''))
[('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o'), ('r', 'l', 'd', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

You'd have to chain them to re-combine them; [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) could do that:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*b, fillvalue='')))
'hello world'
```

This only works for `l = 8`, again, because of overlapping slices for lower values of `l`, For `l > 8`, you start out missing characters from the end as none of the 8 `a[i::l]` slices include those characters

```
>>> for l in range(2, 12):
...     print(f'{l:>2d}:', ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*[a[i::l] for i in range(8)], fillvalue=''))))
...
 2: hello wollo worlo worldworldrldd
 3: hello wolo worldworldld
 4: hello woo worldrld
 5: hello wo worldd
 6: hello woworld
 7: hello woorld
 8: hello world
 9: hello wold
10: hello wod
11: hello wo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't so clear, and we don't know what the `l` really is! if u run it as it is, you will surely get an error saying that the l isn't defined.

However, for the zip function it stops at the shortest iterator, to force it keep going you should use `zip_longest`.

for more details on how zip function works check this : [Python zip](https://www.journaldev.com/15891/python-zip-function)

Comment: Surely there are better resources on `zip` than someone's personal blog?